# Updating branch from another branch, then updating master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Firstly, please let me say that I am well aware that our setup is not "correct" or ideal, but this is how it has been done. I currently have...

1. My development machine, which has a branch (either `dev` or `redesign`) checked out in one folder.
2. On the same development machine, a folder containing the `master` branch
3. A git server on our local network
4. A web server running the `master` branch

When developing, I usually make changes in the `dev` branch, then when happy, merge them into the `master` locally, then push to our local git server and pull from that on our web server.

We then decided to overhaul the interface of our application, so created the `redesign` branch from the current `dev` branch. Since then, a whole host of changes have been made in the `redesign` branch and now I need that branch to essentially become the `master`. The `dev` branch can be overwritten with everything in `redesign`, but it would be ideal to keep the commit history for it if possible.

Being a somewhat inexperienced git user, please can somebody tell me the best process/commands to do this? I am thinking I need to "simply" merge my changes from `redesign` into `dev`, then do as I usually do, merging `dev` into `master` etc. I usually use Sourcetree, but can use CLI if easier.

Thanks!

Comment: " I am thinking I need to "simply" merge my changes from redesign into dev" Yes, that seems reasonable.

Comment: Do you know commands I need to run or the process in Sourcetree to do so?

Comment: Thanks for your help @larsks. If you make this comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I have turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with sourcetree, so I can't address that part of your question, but using `git` that procedure would be:

```
# switch to the dev branch
git checkout dev

# merge in the changes from the redesign branch
git merge redesign

# switch to the master branch
git checkout master

# merge in the changes from the dev branch, which at this point
# include the changes from the redesign branch
git merge dev
```